# Inconsistent Database Relation in Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a GAME table and a SPELL table.
In my game table, I have two spells from the spell table.

```
 //SPELL TABLE
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Game", mappedBy="spell")
 */
 protected $game;

 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->game = new ArrayCollection();
 }

 //GAME TABLE
 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Spell", inversedBy="game")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="spell1", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
 protected $spell1;

 /**
  * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Spell", inversedBy="game")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="spell2", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
 protected $spell2;
```

In my Symfony2 Profiler I get these messages.
"AppBundle\Entity\Game":

> The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Game#spell1 and AppBundle\Entity\Spell#game are inconsistent with each other.
>
> The mappings AppBundle\Entity\Game#spell2 and AppBundle\Entity\Spell#game are inconsistent with each other.

Are these the wrong relations?

Comment: Btw, your `JoinColumn` lines are redundant, as they only state what Doctrine would do by default anyway.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that!